# How can I display the last modified date of the post in octopress?

Tags: utc, octopress, last-modified

New to all this, trying to figure out how can I add a last modified variable to my blog so that when I issue `rake deploy` in git all posts that changed with this commit display the current date (ideally localized). Where should I start looking ?

EDIT: just noticed that on the `sitemap.xml` there is this information:

```
     <url>
         <loc>http://Utumno.github.io/blog/2014/05/02/eclipz/</loc>
-        <lastmod>2014-06-26T19:19:00+01:00</lastmod>
+        <lastmod>2014-07-06T17:36:37+01:00</lastmod>
     </url>
```

So how could I use this ? - I would like to add something in some layout file so all posts display their last modified time - I find it essential for technical posts.